# Get country name from a range of IP number with google sheets script and paste the result in another column

Tags: google-apps-script, scripting, ip

In my Google spreadsheet, in column H I have a list of IP numbers. What I need to a script what will take those numbers and fetch the Country name. I need this to be script since the spreadsheet gets populated from a web-form. What I have is a formula that does that perfectly but I have to copy the formula manually with each form submission. Since I get lots of submissions per day, it's tedious to do this manually. I need the script to run on spreadsheet update. The formula I have is this:

```
=query( importhtml("http://whatismyipaddress.com/ip/" & H1526, "table", 2), "select Col2 where Col1 = 'Country:' ", 0 )
```

The last populated row is H1526. I tried the "ARRAYFORMULA" but no array formulas seems to work with my query function. The column where I have the IPs is H and I need the country name in column I.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write script on submit of the Google form. Also you need to set a trigger for the same. Hope this helps.

[image]

```
function OnSubmit(e){
  var sheetDatabase = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  sheetDatabase.getRange(sheetDatabase.getLastRow(), 8).setFormula('=query(importhtml("http://whatismyipaddress.com/ip/"&I'+sheetDatabase.getLastRow()+', "table", 2), "select Col2 where Col1 = \'Country:\' ", 0 )');
}
```

Comment: Excellent!! It worked!.. I just had to change the 9 for 8 and the "&I" for &H since it was copying the formula in the wrong column and wrong row. But it worked! :D Thanks So much!

Now I have one more question. How can I make the sheet automatically copy the country name that I get by applying your script and paste spacial "paste just value" it in the same cell (meaning replace)? Because when I have 2000+ rows, if I keep the cell with the formula it takes a lot of time for the sheet to retrieve the data. I want to copy paste special after getting the result so that the sheet will load fast.